# Typescript/Angular CLI: Circular dependency with exports

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I create a typescript file which exports all my models:

```
// models.ts

export { TestModel, ITestModel } from './generatedModels/test.model';
export { Test2Model, ITest2Model } from './generatedModels/test2.model';
```

All model-files import the model.ts for the relations (in the following sample to the

```
//test.model.ts

import * as Models from '../models';

export interface ITestModel  {
    testString: string;
    testRelation: Models.ITest2Model;
}

export class TestModel implements ITestModel {
    public testString: string;
    public testRelation: Models.ITest2Model;
}
```

With this way I get the following build warning: `WARNING in Circular dependency detected`

But the major problem is, that I get geh following runtime error:

```
test2.model.ts:7 Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
at __extends (test2.model.ts:7)
at eval (test2.model.ts:12)
at eval (test2.model.ts:30)
```

I can solve the problem by importing the required related models instead over the models.ts: In this sample replace the `import * as Models from '../models';` with `import { Test1Type } from '../models';`. But I need a way to have access to all models, because the model files (test.model.ts, test2.model.ts, ...) will be auto generated with Typewriter (VS Extension).

The affected project is an angular project (angular cli 1.5.0, angular 5.0.1, typescript 2.4.2)

In an other project, which wasn't generated with angular cli und doesn't use webpack this approach works. So is it possible that the problem is webpack?

Have anyone an idea, how I could avoid the runtime error?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue...
With services...they're exported from a `public.ts` and imported from my `app.module.ts`.
But when I import any service in a component from `public` I get the `circular dependency error`, if I import it directly from its `.ts` everything's fine.
Weird. :(